Display an image that is outside the root
My intention is to store the uploaded images at the address:
www.images.domain.com
(images/upload/username/productreference/xxx.jpg)
(Up to 20 images per product)
For now I have created an "Images/Upload" directory that is not under the root (wwwroot) of my project.
This works.
But, I can't display the product images.
<img src needs to point under the root.
My question is not to find a solution for today. Because, while I develop my application, I can temporarily move my 'Upload' directory under the root.
My questions are:

Is this a good way to do it? It seems that many e-commerce sites use a subdomain name to store images
When deploying my site, should I then search for images by https?

Thank you
